# Multiple items from db into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am attempting to pull out some items from a mysql DB and place it into an array. The goal is to have an array so that I can compare 1 variable ($row[0]) to another set variable. Then from that comparison take the second variable ($row[1]) and use that to requery the database.

```
$timestamp = time();
$drop_dead = mysql_query("SELECT drop_dead, ID FROM eblasts") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $last_time[][] = $row[0];
            $last_time[][] = $row[1];   
    };
    foreach($last_time as $value) {
        if($timestamp > $value){
            $final_email[] = $value;
        };
    };
    print_r($final_email)
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Anyone have a better solution? This isn't working ...

There are 4 fields in the DB.  drop_dead, warning1, warning2 and due_date. Each one of these is a unix time stamp.  I need to send an email if that time has past.  So I want to look up the drop_dead date from the DB (which will be the latest time an email should be sent) see how it compares to the current time. Then requery the DB and see which email should be sent out warning1, warning2 etc.

Make sense?

Thanks in advance.

-Adam

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're going for here, but you could probably put this in a single SQL query using `WHERE` and `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $last_time[$row[0]] = $row[1];
    };
    if (array_key_exists($timestamp, $last_time)) {
        $final_email[] = $last_time[$timestamp];
    }
```

assuming that $row[0] is the timestamp and $row[1] is the email..

Comment: Closest one yet! If I change it to while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $last_time[$row[1]] = $row[0]; 
};then I get what I need. But then the foreach doesn't work ...

Comment: you don't need to loop through them. since you have them in an associative array where the 'key' is the value you will be searching for, using array_key_exists automatically checks if that key is in the array. if it is, then your wanted value is the array item of that key. no looping needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this assignment is causing you trouble:

```
$last_time[][] = $row[0];
$last_time[][] = $row[1];
```

Try this instead:

```
$last_time[] = $row[0];
$last_time[] = $row[1];
```

You should also initialize $timestamp with a starting value, even if it's just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you print $row .  It may be an associative array.

Check it first.

`$last_time[][]` also need an index..i hope.

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the $timestamp is defined earlier in the code.

I generally use array_push() for saving items to an array when it is not associative.

try this:

```
$drop_dead = mysql_query("SELECT drop_dead, ID FROM eblasts") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) 
        array_push($last_time, $row);

foreach($last_time as $value)
    if($timestamp > $value[0])
        array_push($final_email, $value[1]);

print_r($final_email)
```

Comment: And yes $timestamp is defined earlier - I edited the above code.

Answer (score 0):

let me have a guess: at last you want to simply drop some records from eblasts...

if drop_dead is a DATETIME or DATE field:

```
"DELETE FROM eblast WHERE drop_dead > NOW()"
```

if drop_dead is an unix_timestamp

```
"DELETE FROM eblast WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(drop_dead) > NOW()"
```

or if you like it complicated ("my" drop_dead id an DATE(TIME) field):

```
DELETE FROM eblast WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM eblasts WHERE drop_dead > NOW())
```

if you need to display the deleted IDs:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM eblasts WHERE drop_dead > NOW()") or die(mysql_error());
$row = array();
while($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM));
array_pop($row);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';

$query = mysql_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM eblast WHERE ID IN(%s)", implode(',', $row))) or die(mysql_error());
```

and still i could be wrong ;)

Comment: HA yup completely wrong. I edited the post to make more sense.